# swarm/io.thorntail : How to have 2 xa-datasources defined and where?

Tags: datasource, wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I need to have 2 xa-datasources for my thorntail/swarm app but I can't understand where to put relevant informations. It seems from what I read that I need to have a project-default.yml file, for exemple :

```
 swarm:
  datasources:
    xa-data-sources:
      statsDS:
        driver-name: postgresql
        connection-url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/stats
        user-name: stats
        password: stats++
      OracleDS:
        driver-name: oracle
        connection-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE
        user-name: ora
        password: ora++
    jdbc-drivers:
      oracle: 
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        xa-datasource-class: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
        driver-module-name: com.oracle
      postgresql:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        xa-datasource-class: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

And some *-ds.xml  files as well, and in these *-ds.xml files I find some identical information than in project-default.yml. For exemple, oracle-ds.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference this 
        in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <xa-datasource
        jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/oracleDS" pool-name="oracle">
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE
        </xa-datasource-property>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>ora</user-name>
            <password>ora++</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker" />
            <stale-connection-checker
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker" />
            <exception-sorter
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter" />
        </validation>
    </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Why the same informations (driver, user, passwd, url) in those 2 files ?

And anyway this conf doesn't work :

```
2018-09-30 14:07:19,377 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("xa-data-source" => "statsDS")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0155: 'jndi-name' may not be null"
```

Just to be complete postgresql-ds.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/statsDS"
        pool-name="PostgresXADS">
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
            jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/stats
        </xa-datasource-property>
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
    <security>
            <user-name>stats</user-name>
            <password>stats++</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker">
            </valid-connection-checker>
            <exception-sorter
                class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter">
            </exception-sorter>
        </validation>
    </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

If I don't use project-default.yml, and only *-ds.xml files, I have :

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.oracleDS\" is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle]"]
```

I may precise that I have a module.xml and ojdbcxxx.jar in my resources/modules/com/oracle/main directory.

So how should I do to have my 2 XA-datasources working in my project ?
Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, no need of *-ds.xml files everything that is in those files could be in project-default.yml. Finally my project-default.yml looks like :

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    xa-data-sources:
      statsDS:
        driver-name: postgresql
        jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/statsDS
        user-name: stats
        password: stats++
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter
        xa-datasource-properties:
          URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/stats

      oracleDS:
        driver-name: oracle
        jndi-name: java:jboss/datasources/oracleDS
        user-name: ora
        password: ora++
        valid-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker
        validate-on-match: true
        background-validation: false
        stale-connection-checker-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker
        exception-sorter-class-name: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter
        xa-datasource-properties:
          URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE

    jdbc-drivers:
      oracle: 
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        xa-datasource-class: oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource
        driver-module-name: com.oracle
      postgresql:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        xa-datasource-class: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource
        driver-module-name: org.postgresql
```

Then take care of having the right modules in your resources directory.
And that's all.

Hope it could help some people, because I found the doc a little poor about this.

Comment: Well :( Now I have ```XADataSourceClass is undefined``` So modules seems OK to me (they work in regular wildfly).... I'm lost ...

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Configure the URL properties as follows:

```
 xa-datasource-properties:
      URL: 
        value: jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1521:XE
```

I got the solution from this thread: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-1270

It took me some time to figure this out.